# Can't seem to get custom code modules to be recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using WinPython 3.4.3.1 x64 on Win 7.  I can't seem to get it to work with custom code modules.  It throws errors along the lines of:

```
ImportError:  No module named 'xxx'
```

I edited winpython.ini to add the appropriate paths to PYTHONPATH.  I've tried adding both the parent folder as well as the child folders.  It looks something like:

```
PYTHONPATH = C:\Prog Data\Python Modules, C:\Prog Data\Python Modules\test1\mod1, C:\Prog Data\Python Modules\test2\mod2
```

I tried verifying that the paths were being seen by doing:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

All the paths I added were right at the front (after an empty list item).

So I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Any ideas?

Edit:  To clarify, each module folder does have an `__init__.py` file in it.  The parent folder does not, but that's why I added the specific module folders as well.

Comment: What kind of custom modules are we talking about? Are they modules you wrote? In C/C++ or in python?

Comment: @jfish003:  They are simply other code that's shared by multiple projects (some written by me, some written by others - but it's not a public library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down the problem.  The issue is NOT something that is clearly documented, so I'm going to put it here for anyone who experiences the same problem.

Paths specified in PYTHONPATH **must** be one level above any desired packages.  It CANNOT be the path of the package itself, NOR can it be a path where the package is more than one level deep.

**Example:**

Folder structure:

C:\Code Data\Python Data\Package 1\__init__.ini

C:\Code Data\Python Data\Package 2\__init__.ini

```
# These will NOT work:
PYTHONPATH = C:\Code Data
PYTHONPATH = C:\Code Data\Python Data\Package 1

# This WILL work:
PYTHONPATH = C:\Code Data\Python Data
```